# Remove Dollar sign from Column value(Indian Currency) Yii2 kartik gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

Below is the snapshot of my index page in Yii2 with Kartik Gridview widget;

[image]

Below is the gridview code for the same.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
        ],
        //'line_id',
         'metal_name',
         'item',
         'unit_name',
         'weight',
        ['attribute' => 'quantity',
            'pageSummary' =>(true),
            'value' => function ($model) {
                if($model){
                    return  $model->quantity;
                }
            }],
         'rate_per_gram',
         'making_charges',
        [
            'attribute' => 'total',
            'format'=>'currency',
            'pageSummary' =>(true),
            'value' => function ($model) {
                            if($model){
                                return $model->total;
                            }
                        }
        ],
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'export'=>false,
    'showPageSummary' => true,
]); ?>
```

1. I have tried lot of stuff to get plain number format with 2 decimals, but i could succeed in one.
2. How can I Format my **Total** column with Indian Currency, viz. **Rs. 35670.00** or just **35670.00**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set currency directly:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'total',
    'format' => ['currency', 'INR'],
    'pageSummary' => true,
],
```

PS. You don't need to set value key unless you want to replace it with something else in certain case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bizley! You always save my time.

Comment: Another format without currency that i got seeing the source code for kartik gridview is   'format'=>['decimal', 2],